# Is it possible to override a file which exist in the framework in Swift?

Tags: swift

I added a framework to my swift project. The framework is a react native project.

There is a file which handles toolbox buttons. I can add and remove buttons from there. 
Is it possible to override a file which is in the framework?

Or any other suggestion which makes it possible for me to change the framework behavior.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to create an extension for the class(es) you want to make changes to and then handle all overrides inside there.

Comment: Plugin pattern, for instance, could do for you, where you could form your behaviors as objects and basically register/unregister behaviors.